# Are there specific performance benefits to upgrading a WinForms app from .NET 3.5 to the 4.6.x?

Tags: .net, performance

I have a number of older winforms apps that are on .NET 3.5.  I've read about a lot of speed improvements for later .NET frameworks but they seemed to be focused on the server side.

Are there any specific performance benefits I would reap on a WinForms side that are documented somewhere?

Comment: We can't answer this. You'll need to measure it. Performance enhancements in general are in the runtime, so you won't have to recompile to benefit from them. Also, WinForms apps in general don't have any performance problemsl the most time spent waiting is for I/O. In other words: it depends entirely on your application, but I doubt you'll notice any difference.

Comment: If your application peruses some libraries that have been optimized for 4.6, then likely it would be.

Answer (score -2):

See the new features for each ASP.Net version and you would be able to determine whether your code heavily uses some libraries that have been optimized.

[What's New in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[.NET 4.6.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#v461)

[.NET 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)